# how could I modify/recompile an already defined function during runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x

Firstly, yes I know this is not good practice. It's just an experiment, not actual planned code.

The problem:
I have a function

```
def foo:
    print("hi there")

def foo2:
    #Any stack/recompiling manipulation goes here

def main:
    foo2()
    foo()
```

Is there any way to manipulate the definition of foo() from foo2() during runtime?

I have been fiddling with trying to change variables in the frames, but most are read only (save f_local).

Comment: completely depends on what you are trying to modify, if it fits any use case that might come up in the real world there may be things you can do with decorators/factory functions but we need to know what you want to do with it.

Comment: What are "variables in the frames"?

Comment: The variable I most wanted to change is f_code. From there I would hope to change main to do things such as skip over foo() entirely.

Comment: @JonathanBurk please tell us what you are actually trying to do.  The more specific you can be the more likely we can give you what you need.  just saying you want to "modify it at runtime" is far to vague to get decent answers.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen you have answered my original question. I was wondering as an extra step, can you do something like the above code, but let's say there is now foo3() after foo() in main. Could you modify execution to entirely skip foo3() using only foo2()

Thank you all for the help, sorry for the confusion on my part.

Comment: @TheYargonaut when you are learning it's good to see examples of good code and mess around with internals to learn how things work. You have gotten an answer for both of these and you are now asking for an example of how to mess around with internals.  This worries me because it suggests you are not just doing this for educational purposes but trying to accomplish something which **python is designed to not let you mess with**.  An example that modifies the stack directly mid-execution puts your computer at risk to even play with.  I will ask one more time: **What do you actually want to do?**

Comment: Responding with "I just want to learn about the stack" is valid, I can point you to non-manipulative resources in that case, but I really think that anything else has a better solution than low level monkey patching.

Comment: I agree with you, I'm just trying to figure out for intrigue how far it can go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in byte code level stuff in python let me introduce `dis`, `compile` and `CodeType`

**don't do any of this in production code**

You can `compile` python code (as a string) into a Code object which can then override a functions `__code__` property

```
def foo():
    print('hi there')
code_stuff = compile("print('this is hacked in')", "dummy file", "exec")
foo.__code__ = code_stuff
foo() #prints "this is hacked in"
```

if you want to modify more than a no inputs no outputs function take a look at the `types.CodeType` constructor:

```
>>> import types
>>> help(types.CodeType)
Help on class code in module builtins:

class code(object)
 |  code(argcount, kwonlyargcount, nlocals, stacksize, flags, codestring,
 |        constants, names, varnames, filename, name, firstlineno,
 |        lnotab[, freevars[, cellvars]])
 |  
 |  Create a code object.  Not for the faint of heart.
 |  ...
```

Which - much like writing assembly code - involves risking seg-faults, crashing the python interpreter or worse.  You know when the only documentation is `Not for the faint of heart.` the developer was not intending for it to be directly used.

if you want to see what byte code actually executes as you can use `dis`. which is short for "disassemble"

```
def foo():
    print('hi there')

import dis
dis.dis(foo)
```

This is interesting to see how python code actually executes.

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do with the stack but I'm fairly certain what ever it is, the developers of python have made sure it's not easy since that is not something you should be touching in python. These types only exist in python for introspection reasons (like seeing what the arguments of a function are at runtime by inspecting it's call signature)

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. Is there any way to modify the execution flow with this method? For example, if we now wish to overwrite main() from foo()

Comment: If you want to screw with a function's internals, this is only the tip of the iceberg, though. There are a lot more fiddly bits, version-specific details, and other things to get right, and especially if you try to construct code objects directly, it's easy to segfault your interpreter.

Comment: @JonathanBurk: Nope. Replacing a function's code object won't change the code object for calls already on the stack.

Comment: Good to know. Is there any way to jump to lines/skip lines by manipulating the stack?

Comment: @TheYargonaut see [my other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52884144/how-could-i-modify-recompile-an-already-defined-function-during-runtime/52884319#comment92681881_52884144) tell us exactly what you want to do and we can help. Less technical like "manipulate the stack" and more detailed like "I want to abort a function mid execution and fake it to return a specific value"

Comment: @TheYargonaut: Sort of, but with a lot of restrictions on where you can jump, and CPython pretty much only lets debuggers do it. Writing a trace function to gain access to the functionality is yet another can of worms, as is figuring out what the right line numbers are and/or making sure your code object actually has meaningful line numbers.

Comment: Also, seconding the point about telling us exactly what you want to do. This question is too vague and broad as it stands.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manipulate the definition of `foo`, it's straightforward to redefine `foo` much the same way you would assign any other global variable, with a `global` statement and `=`:

```
def foo():
    print('hi there')

def foo2():
    global foo
    def replacement_foo():
        print('hi from over here')
    foo = replacement_foo

def main():
    foo2()
    foo()

main()
```

It's probably also safe to just `def foo(): ...` inside `foo2` instead of defining `replacement_foo` and then assigning, but that's [officially not permitted](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement), even though the implementation doesn't enforce it.

---

In the comments, you seem to be very interested in manipulating `foo` through the stack somehow. The definition of `foo` doesn't live on the stack, and no call to `foo` is on the stack during the execution of `foo`, so the stack is the wrong place to look.

Also, most of Python's stack inspection is read-only. Even if you were to reassign a function's code object, it wouldn't change the code of calls already on the stack. You can't change `main`'s code object to make it not call `foo` (though you can change `foo`'s code object, and that'll take effect when `main` calls `foo`).

Comment: This doesn't modify the original function `foo`, though, it replaces it with a completely unrelated function by reassigning to the global name `foo`. (Which might or might not be what the OP is looking for.)

Comment: That's true, although that does help, I'm wondering if it's possible to replace things in the stack. For example, modifying the current line/place in the execution flow, changing the underlying bytecode of main etc.

Comment: @JonathanBurk: `foo` isn't *on* the stack when `foo2` runs, so I'm not sure why you're talking about the stack. Is your goal to fiddle with the stack? It didn't sound like it from your question.

Comment: Wouldn't main have the execution flow with something like foo2() then foo() then end?

Comment: @JonathanBurk: Yes. `foo` still isn't on the stack when `foo2` runs, though. You asked about manipulating the definition of `foo`, so I wrote an answer that redefines `foo`.

Comment: Yes, I don't think I properly asked the question. Sorry. I am trying to redefine foo by manipulating the stack/frames (I am new to Python, so forgive me if my description is poor)